# GeoServer WPS RasterZonalStatistics missing out pixels

Tags: geoserver, statistics, wps

I am trying to get stats back on a raster for a given polygon.

The raster is a 0.5 degree grid with each pixel having a numeric value

The location of a point is determined by the top left corner in the image

When I try to get stats on an area that just goes over a pixel I would expect to get both pixels included in the stats, but only the one where the AOI covers the top left corner is being included

The orange area represent the AOI and the yellow and purple pixels below are what I need to return for the stats

[image]

Is there any way when cropping the image to get it to return the polygon of the union of every pixel the AOI covers?

I can do this by rasterizing the image, but the aim here is to use the image without any conversion allowing for updated images to be dropped in for replacement

I am using the Geotools RasterZonalStatistics.java and my problems occur around the "CoverageCrop" operation

In this particular example "DouglasPeuckerSimplifier.simplify" actually gave me back a "POLYGON EMPTY" with tolerance 1!!

My image has bounds

> ows:LowerCorner-180.3125 -58.25</ows:LowerCorner>
>
> ows:UpperCorner179.6875 75.25</ows:UpperCorner>

This AOI is

> gml:coordinates2.125,15.750 2.625,15.750 2.625,15.250 2.125,15.250 2.125,15.750</gml:coordinates>

Comment: The DP tolerance is in map units so 1is way too big. In general rasterStats isn't designed to deal with 2 or 3 pixel rasters.